# Protobuf issues with imposm.parser on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, imposm

I have been trying to install `imposm.parser` on my MBPro (OSX El Capitan) via `pip`. I am getting the following error

```
In file included from imposm/parser/pbf/osm.cc:6:
    imposm/parser/pbf/osm.pb.h:9:10: fatal error: 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found
    #include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
         ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I already installed protobuf and py2-protobuf using Macports. I also installed Google's Protocol Buffers 2.6.1 from source, but it does not address the issues. Note that the file `common.h` is actually in the `google/protobuf/stubs` folder when I checked.

Comment: I am running into the same issue, so I am hoping someone has any tips to help this!  In my case, I think it might have something to do with installing protobuf from homebrew, but not having that linked properly to the system python that imposm can see.